# Declaring User Defined Variable in Shell Scripting (csh shell)

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I am trying to learn shell scripting and trying to create a user defined variable within the script, `first`:

```
howdy="Hello $USER !"
echo $howdy
```

However, when I execute the script (`./first`) I get this:

```
howdy=Hello aaron!: Command not found.
howdy: Undefined variable.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What shell flavor? bash, ksh, zsh, ... ?

Comment: I didn't know it mattered but it is csh

Comment: Here's an indication how much it matters: [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Comment: Each shell has its own language, with its own syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two errors in you code:

1. you are using sh syntax instead of csh one to set the variable
2. you are not escaping the "!" character (history substitution)

Try this:

```
#!/bin/csh

set howdy="Hello $USER \!"
echo $howdy
```

Answer (score 1):

`csh` expects that you `set` variables. Try

```
set howdy="Hello $USER"
echo $howdy
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
howdy=''Hello $USER !''
```

You need to enclose the string in double quotes as:

```
howdy="Hello $USER !"
```

You seem to be using two single quotes in place of a double quote.

Comment: That was typo when putting it into stack overflow, sorry